# How to group endpoints in swagger for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, swagger, documentation

Grouping API's were impossible for me, in NodeJS. Various approaches seen, weren't as simplified as expected; as the endpoints still maintained the default swagger grouping. The approach below made things work.

Answer (score 0):

For NodeJS, it is expected that in your swagger.js or swagger.ts file,
you've got the following;

#### swagger.js file

```
   swagger: "2.0",
    info: {
        title: 'My API',
        description: 'My API docs',
    },
    host: 'localhost:9000/api/v1',
    schemes: ['http', 'https'],
    tags: [
        {
          name: 'Patient Management',
          description: "Patient Management"
        },
        {
            name: 'Doctor Management',
            description: "Doctor Management"
        },
        ...
        ...
    ]
}
```

Then in your controller files, you're expected to have the following;

#### Get Doctor Controller

```
const GetDoctorsController = (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    // #swagger.tags = ['Doctor Management']
    try{
    }catch(error){
    }
}
```

Run the script for your api & run the link on your browaer